# How to add manipulate param in jquery

Tags: jquery, url, param

I have a question about manipulation param in jQuery.
I need to build a URL.

This is my code:

```
function CollectMenuElemente(sender, eventArgs) {

    var VID = $('input[id$=hfVermittlerID]').val();
    var obj = { ID: VID };

    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        var tbVal = $('#txtMenuElement' + i).val()
        obj += { pa: tbVal };
    }
}
```

How can I add dynamically param to my object `obj`?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to add to obj

```
$.extend(obj, {
    pa: tbVal
});
```

*Note: The variable **pa** must be different otherwise it will just replace the existing object pa*

**Update**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    var tbVal = $('#txtMenuElement' + i).val()
    obj["pa" + i] = tbVal
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. But how can i reach a different variable? :/

Comment: Its a value from a input field that i add dynamically. So there can be several of them, because the user can add them by himself.

Comment: I've updated the answer you could do it like that, giving objects "pa1","pa2"......"pa8" @egolive